# Google Spreadsheet - Use tab name as reference in formula

Tags: google-sheets

this question is a bit difficult to formulate.

I have 3 tabs.
1 is called "ABC".
1 is called "XYZ".
1 is called "Pivot".

Tab 1 and tab 2 have the same column headers, but different data and different number of rows.

The Pivot tab contains a pivot table in cell A3.

What I want to do is write the name of the tab in cell B2.
And the pivot table should get the data like that.
So instead of changing the range of the pivot table each time from
"ABC!A1:J" to "XYZ!A1"

I simply want to write "ABC" or "XYZ" in cell B2 and set the range of the pivot table to something dynamic like "$B2!A1:J" but this throws an error.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function can give you what you need. It allows you to write a string like `INDIRECT(C3&"!A1")`. When the value in C3 of the same sheet is equal to `Foo`, the string inside the brackets is `Foo!A1`, and the Indirect function will return the value found in the `Foo` sheet at A1.

Also be aware of the accompanying [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472) function, which does almost the opposite - it returns a cell reference as a string. The two pair well together.

Comment: Hi, I think this is definitely in the right direction but not there yet. When I input "=INDIRECT(B2&"!A1:J")" or "INDIRECT(BB&"!A1:J100")" in a cell, it works, i.e. it basically just copies that entire range. However in the pivot table it doesn't seem to work (it says "Enter a valid range."). Maybe pivot table is an exception where it can't be used? What do you think?